# Can I disable my Wireless when laptop docked and enable when undocked?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Does anyone know a way to automatically configure wireless to be disabled when LAN is connected?  Then I can just dock, use the LAN, un-dock and use the Wireless?
So the second question might be: Wht does the OS not follow the Adapter priority as listed in Network Advanced Settings?

Background: I have a laptop with a port docker, at work I want to use the fast LAN, but when away from work I use the wireless.  The wireless at work seems to take precedence over the LAN and its really slow.  It often takes me a while to recognize and mash the wireless disable switch at the front of the laptop which also disables bluetooth.  It would be great if this was auto-magic.

Good suggestion to check the order of the Adapters however I found that the Local Area Connection was already listed at the top.  But the wireless still takes precedence.

[image: Network Advanced Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click Start and, in the search field, type View network connections.
2. Press the ALT key, click Advanced Options and then click Advanced Settings...
3. Select Local Area Connection and click the green arrows to give priority to the desired connection.
4. After organizing the network connections available according to your preferences, click OK.
5. The computer will now follow an order of priority when detecting available connections.

Comment: Have checked, but if I understand the Connections box, the Local Area Connection is the highest priority but its not behaving like that.  Have edited the question to provide more information.